# Mirror cells when a change in either cell updates the other

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, mirroring, links

Gary's Student answered this question before and it worked great for only 1 cell per sheet.
If I wanted to mirror multiple cells what could I do? I have tried the following and it does not work.  I do not get errors but nothing happens.  I am new to VBA BTW.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set r1 = Range("C3:D3")
Set r2 = Sheets("Flight Planning").Range("K1:K2")
If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    r2.Value = r1.Value
Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim r3 As Range, r4 As Range
Set r3 = Range("E22")
Set r4 = Sheets("Flight Planning").Range("B4")
If Intersect(Target, r3) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    r4.Value = r3.Value
Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim r5 As Range, r6 As Range
Set r5 = Range("E24")
Set r6 = Sheets("Flight Planning").Range("C4:D4")
If Intersect(Target, r5) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    r6.Value = r5.Value
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you upload an image capture of your excel sheet that you are working on to give more context to the problem you're having? Or upload a copy of a similar excel sheet.

Comment: Just looking at the logic, I think I may have found your problem. Including blank lines, look at lines 6, 14, 22. What do you notice? Just thinking about logical steps. If line 6 is true then the rest of the code will not be looked at, at all. Is this what's intended? You are asking the program to exit. Have you any programming experience at all? I noticed that you are new to VBA, but what I mention is logic which is encountered in any programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave you a couple comments to ponder. But I offer you this solution, <strike>**temporary**</strike>, so that you can *see* a possible fix. Please let me know if this helps your logic.

If the temporary solution I present below solves what you are working on, please mark the box as solution accepted, so that it is know that this is now closed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set r1 = Range("C3:D3")
Set r2 = Sheets("Flight Planning").Range("K1:K2")
If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  MsgBox "(1) Nothing" 'Let me know
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
    r2.Value = r1.Value
  Application.EnableEvents = True
EndIf

Dim r3 As Range, r4 As Range
Set r3 = Range("E22")
Set r4 = Sheets("Flight Planning").Range("B4")
If Intersect(Target, r3) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  MsgBox "(2) Nothing" 'Let me know
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
      r4.Value = r3.Value
  Application.EnableEvents = True
EndIf

Dim r5 As Range, r6 As Range
Set r5 = Range("E24")
Set r6 = Sheets("Flight Planning").Range("C4:D4")
If Intersect(Target, r5) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  MsgBox "(3) Nothing" 'Let me know or leave line blank
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
      r6.Value = r5.Value
  Application.EnableEvents = True
EndIf


End Sub
```

A single " ' " is making a comment, which comments the rest of the line to the right and is ignored. It should turn green in the Excel environment. You can comment the Msgbox out completely with a single quote.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have absolutely no coding experience. I am trying to learn as much as I can and forums like this really help me understand errors.

Comment: You go it! Keep on learning!