# (How) can I share a column between two sheets in an Excel workbook?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2016

My spreadsheet has become too wide. I had thought to split it across two tabs, as it is just tabular data, rather than calculations.

The leftmost column (A) is text to explain what each row is about.

(How) can I share, reference it, pin it, freeze it, such that I only have one copy and when I switch tabs/sheets it is always visible?  Excel 2016, if that is important.

Comment: There is no such feature. Simply refer to according cell of 1st sheet in 2nd sheet's cell by the formula and protect this column.

Comment: If you are 100% certan of that, then feel free to post it as ana answer. It's maybe not what I had hoped to hear, but it is useful info for others who read this question in future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mirror cells so that a change in either cell updates the other](https://superuser.com/questions/835301/mirror-cells-so-that-a-change-in-either-cell-updates-the-other)

Comment: (1) I agree that (AFAIK) there is no such feature.  I would suggest a slightly different approach: actually put the data in columns in both sheets, and use [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/835301/150988 "Mirror cells so that a change in either cell updates the other") to keep them in sync.  See other versions [here](https://superuser.com/q/1094218/150988 "2"), [here](https://superuser.com/q/813639/150988 "3"), [here](https://superuser.com/q/1199707/150988 "4"), [here](https://superuser.com/q/700930/150988 "5"), and [here](https://superuser.com/q/649311/150988 "6").  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I’m not inclined to post an answer, either, since I believe that this is a duplicate question. (2) Do you really not know how to freeze columns?

Comment: 1) then vote to close as dupe; I wouldn't object. And, 2) no, I did not know how to freeze columns until yesterday - I am not gnerally an Excel user, but I just tried freeing column A on sheet 1m, then switchign to sheet 2, where I did not se eit and is what I was hoping to achieve. Thanks for your help (upvote). Reckon I should delete this question?